# Use ng-repeat variable inside ng-model names

Tags: angularjs

`<ng-model="formData.alert_settings.{{alert}}" ng-repeat="alert in alerts">`

I wanted ng-model names to be `formData.alert_settings.down`, `formData.alert_settings.up`, etc.

where :
`alerts={down,up,trouble , ...}`

This way `formData.alert_settings.{{alert}}` is not working.
Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have this in your controller:

```
$scope.formData = {alert_settings: {}}
$scope.alerts=['down','up','trouble'];
```

Then you can do this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="formData.alert_settings[alert]" ng-repeat="alert in alerts">
```

and you will end up with three inputs and the data will be in formData.alert_settings.down, and so on

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
ng-model="formData.alert_settings.alert
```

Comment: No instead of formData.alert_settings.down it is taking the variable as formData.alert_settings.alert if i specify as you said